# screen resolution issue in centos hdmi

Tags: centos, resolution, hdmi

i am using centos7
my system has vga and HDMI port 
if i connect to vga its working fine
but if i connect to HDMI its showing gray screen(grains)
but somehow i can change resolution manually
first i have to select 1920x1080i
it will show flickering screen
then change back to 1920x1080 then it will work fine

But after system reboot same issue

How can i solve this issue?

my xrandr is below

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 260mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00* 
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00    60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
```

I am using zebronic motherboard 
i5 processor

startup screen
[image: startup screen]

Comment: May you please update the question to include the type of computer you are using and information about the graphics card? Try out the following command to get this information ```lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d```

Comment: @Gordster 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)

Comment: please add a  couple of blank lines before the `lspci ...` line so that it does not run into the xrandr listing